# this keyword doesn't represent an object

Tags: java

Does anyone know why can we loop through the "this" keyword here (in the subsetOf method)? To my knowledge this represents a JAVA object. Some extensive explanations are welcomed, would like to know why "this" can work in this way.

```
public class ArrayListSet<E> implements Set<E> {

    private ArrayList<E> elements;

    public ArrayListSet() {
        elements = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E e) {
        if (!elements.contains(e))
            elements.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E e) {
        elements.remove(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object e) {
        return elements.contains(e);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean subsetOf(Set<?> other) {
        for (E e : this) {
            if (!other.contains(e))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are declaring a class which implements the `Set` *interface* which itself extends the `Iterable` through the `Collection` interface. Any Object which is an implementation of the `Iterable` interface can be used inside a for-each loop.

So the inheritance hierarchy is this for your class:

```
 Iterable
    ^
    |
Collection
    ^
    |
   Set
    ^
    |
ArrayListSet
```

Also the `this` keyword always refers to the current instance. In your code when you execute the `subsetOf()` the `this` will point to an instance of `ArrayListSet` (which was used to invoke the `subSetOf()` method) which is a type of `Iterable` through inheritance, so you can use it in a for-each loop.

Also since you are implementing a `Set` you need to supply an implementation of the `Iterator<E> iterator();` method defined in the `Set` interface to make it an `Iterable`.

As implementations of the `Iterable` interface requires a `iterator()` method which returns an instance of the `Iterator` object. The `Iterator` Object will be used by the for-each loop to iterate over the elements of the `ArrayListSet`.

The implementation of the `Iterator` type returned from the `iterator()` method actually defines the iteration logic used by the for-each loop.

To use any Object in a for-each loop:

Step 1: Extend `Iterable` directly or through other `Iterable` types.

Step 2: Provide implementation of the `Iterator iterator()` method inherited from the `Iterable` interface.

Step 3: Implement an `Iterator` and return its instance from the `iterator()` method.

Comment: Why "this" refers to the instance variable in this case (children of Iterable) but not for other cases (not children of Iterable)?

Comment: so for example, if I add another instance variable to my class would that make a difference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The `this` is the the instance of this class itself. It has nothing to do with its fields and variables.

Comment: @StephenFong The `this` usage in your case will point to the instance of the `ArrayListSet` class which will be used to invoke the the `subsetOf()` method i.e. if I call `new ArrayListSet().subsetOf()` the `this` will point to the `new ArrayListSet()` object I created.

Comment: What I get confused is for (E e : this), as this =/= elements, however, if I change the for loop into for (E e : elements), the program works fine as well, therefore, I have confusion on whether this represents the variable

Comment: @StephenFong yes if you change it to `for (E e : elements)` it will also work because the `elements` is an `ArrayList` type which is also a type of `Iterable` so the same logic applies.

Comment: What if now I add another variable of type ArrayList in the ArrayListSet class (So now there're two array list)? What would happen if I use "this" in the for loop

Comment: @StephenFong the `this` **always** points to the instance which was used to invoke your method so it doesn't really matter whether you add one or n number of `ArrayList ` fields in your class.

Comment: @StephenFong btw your current code won't compile as your are not correctly implementing the `add()` and `remove()` methods inherited from the `Set` interface. They require a `boolean` return type and you are using `void`.

Comment: But isn't that in for each loop its syntax is like (for (type var : array)) if now array is replaced by an object, what does it represent?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, that's just a part of my code. However, my origin program actually run without error even return type are not boolean

Comment: @StephenFong that is what I said in my answer, you can replace the array with an Object also provided the Object is a type of `Iterable`. The Object should also define the iteration logic by implementing the `iterator` method.

Comment: That means the iterator method allow an object to be looped through?

Comment: @StephenFong yes, the for-each uses the `iterator()` method to get an instance of a `Iterator`. Then the `next()` method of an `Iterator` is used to get the elements out of the `Iterator`.

Comment: Your current implementation would not iterate your actual elements, it would be empty. You need to override `iterator()` and tell it to use your custom `elements`. There is no magic attaching it to your field, you need to tell it to use the field.

Comment: When you say an instance of a Iterator, do you mean the object that call the subsetOf method or the ArrayList elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through this since it represents a set. The [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is [iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). Therefore it is valid syntax.

Comment: Why Java decide to loop through the ArrayList "elements" in my ArrayListSet class?